# ubuntu: profile.d and .bash_profile missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have done some reading up on Linux startup, etc and I noticed that in my home directory it is not present a folder `profile.d`:

> `/home/user/profile.d/       # Doesn't exists`

and nor a file `.bash_profile`:

> `/home/user/.bash_profile    # Doesn't exists`

is there a reason for this?

*Ubuntu 15.04, gnome*

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** it is ok so.

There are many initialization user files because an user can decide to log in a computer account in many different way, from console, with an interactive or a non interactive shell, with different kind of shells. It is not a prerogative of all the users, but with the need to keep a [backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) it finished to complicate *a little* the things. :-)

- A directory `profile.d` **should not to be under your home directory**:
  `/etc/profile.d` contains scripts with application-specific startup files, which are also executed at startup time by the shell.
  It is a directory valid for all the users, for this it is created under the `/etc/` path and not under each single user home directory.
- The file `~/.bash_profile` is one of the personal initialization files and when it exists is stored in each user home. **But it is not needed that it exists.** It should contain the bash-specific commands to be run when starting a login shell (`~/.profile` can be read from different shells too, that usually understand a syntax different from the bash one).

---

Reading more from the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash`

> When  bash  is  invoked  as an interactive login shell (...) **it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`**, if that file exists.
> After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, **in that order,** and reads and
> **executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable**.

So if you have a `~/.bash_profile` file it will not be read the `~/.profile`, if not called (or sourced) in one of the other files.

Note that

> When  an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist.

From some version of Ubuntu 12 (and for sure from 13.10) in the `.profile` is sourced the `~/.bashrc`.

> This can cause unexpected behavior when running login shells (such as when `ssh` into the machine for example) where the user would not expect to have `~/.bashrc` sourced.

**Reference:**

- In the Bash (not so) Beginner Guide, the section about the [Shell initialization files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)
- [Why does Ubuntu's default ~/.profile source ~/.bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432508/why-does-ubuntus-default-profile-source-bashrc)